# How to read environment variables in travis-ci for Lumen application

Tags: laravel-5, travis-ci, lumen, phpdotenv

I have a Lumen application that is using the Dotenv library from vlucas. When trying to deploy, travis-ci complains that there is no ".env" file. Do I need to modify my bootstrap/app.php file to conditionally load the Dotenv class, or is there a better way to handle this?

The error message that I'm getting is:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Dotenv: Environment file .env not found or not readable. Create file with your environment settings at /home/travis/build/project/repo/bootstrap/../.env' in /home/travis/build/project/repo/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Dotenv.php:33

Answer (score 0):

Be careful that the .env file at the root of your Lumen project is in the .gitignore shipped with Lumen.

If the file isn't relevant for you, you can comment the `Dotenv::load(__DIR__.'/../');` line at the top of `bootstrap/app.php`.